# How to define non-empty set in Coq?

Tags: math, set, coq

Trying to create my first Coq definitions after doing many tutorials. Wondering how to define something simple like an alphabet, if the definition is:

> Σ is an alphabet iff it's a finite nonempty set of symbols.

Got this much:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.ListSet.

Definition alphabet := set.
```

But how do you specify the "must be a finite, non-empty set" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you choose your `alphabet` to be `set`, it is by definition finite, since `set` is defined as an instance of `list`, and inductive types are always finite.

The `ListSet` library you are using defines `emptyset` so your first option would be to state that

```
Definition not_empty (a: alphabet) : Prop := a <> empty_set.
```

Or you could rely on the fact that your set is `list` and pattern match on the expression:

```
Definition not_empty (a: alphabet) : bool := match a with
  | nil => false
  | _ => true
end.
```

(You can also define the latter in `Prop` instead of `bool` by using `False` and `True`.)

EDIT: Some clarification asked by Arthur (Simplification here, grab a real text-book about inductive types if you want a more precise explanation):

An inductive type can be inhabited by:

- a finite number of elements (for example, `bool`),
- an infinite number of elements (for example, `nat`)
- no element at all (for example `False`).

However, any element of an inductive type is by construction finite. For example you can write any natural number by composing a finite number of time the constructor `S` but you *have* to use `O` at some point and ''stop'' the construction of your term. Same goes for lists: you can build an arbitrary long list, but its length will always be finite.

Comment: I think you could add some clarification on "inductive types are always finite", since it could be taken to mean that an inductive type has finitely many elements.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim Agreed, I think "instances of inductive types are always finite" is more precise.